# How to manage socket connections with same IP and different remote ports?

Tags: vb.net, sockets, tcp

I have a Server that clients can connect to it through a port. I monitor connected clients with CurrPorts Software.
I develop server code with vb.net and socket programming. I have an `ArraylList` that stores socket connections of all clients.
When I monitored connections on the port in CurrPorts, I saw that every client had more than one connections to the server with same IP and different remote ports.
With this situation, when I close the repeated connections for a client all connections of the client are closed.
How can I manage socket connections with same IP and different remote ports?

Comment: "*... control socket connections ...*" in which sense?

Comment: my clients have connections with same IP and different remote ports, I want to save only one of the connections for every client.

Comment: So, did the code close the client side socket?

Comment: my code polls sockets and checks the availability of them every 3 minutes. if a client didn't response to the server, the server closes its socket.

Comment: To turn my question around: Does the client code also close the socket(s) or simply ends when the socket(s) aren't needed anymore?

Comment: After a socket got closed it hangs around for a will before the ssystem rleases all resources used by it.